# How to make measurements DPI independent

Tags: wpf

Please read my problem before answering, I know all the suggestions about "make a liquid layout", etc...

I want to display a full screen app with a background image in FullHD(1920x1080 aka 1080p) assuming the screen resolution is also 1080p and this should work **regardless of the DPI setting** of the monitor. In other words the background image should occupy the whole screen in 1080p resolution.

Another complication: This background image has several rectangular areas where I want to place other secondary images into.

The root element will be a Canvas and onto that I stack the background image and then the secondary stuff(photo images, buttons, etc...) All these have to be properly aligned with the background.

See the drawing below:

```
----------------------------------------
|   Background image with rectangular area below
|      ___________________________
|     |                           |
|     |                           |
|     | Picture area with         | 
|     | secondary image stacked   |
|     | on top                    |
|     |                           |
```

The question is: how to do that?

First note the following equation(desiredPixels are what you write in your XAML, realPixels is what appears on the monitor and DPI is your monitor DPI).

```
realPixels = desiredPixels*DPI/96
```

Implying:

```
desiredPixels = realPixels * 96 / DPI
```

See http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/11/30/wpf-is-dpi-depended.aspx

The idea I have come up with(but not yet implemented) is to first design your XAML using the real pixel sizes and then after the Layout phase, programatically walk down the logical tree and adjust all  Canvas.Left, Canvas.Top, Width and Height measurements by multiplying them with `96/DPI`.

Do you agree? Any better solutions?

Edit: I just finished reading the blog post I linked. He has the suggestion of using a custom markup to do the converesion in the elements.

Edit2: The application has to run on different machines with potentially different DPI settings. So it has to dynamically read the DPI value and adjust the layout accordingly.

Comment: Full screen is full screen, regardless of anything else. You don't have to walk visual trees or convert to "real pixels." Create the canvas you want, put it in a `ViewBox`, and everything scales up and down with it.

Comment: @Jay Yeah, that is probably the way to do it, so simple. I feel stupid right now :(

Comment: @Jay Thinking about it a bit more I'm not sure it will work. If my background image is scaled, will the same happen to the *position* of elements set with `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`? If not those elements will *not* be in the right location after the scaling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on the from the comments, yes, everything inside a `Viewbox` will scale proportionally, and that includes the positions of elements on a canvas.

Here is a red `Rectangle` on a blue `Canvas`, inside a `Viewbox`. `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` on the `Rectangle` are both set to 20 device-independent units.

At startup:

[image]

When the window is scaled up:

[image]

When the window is scaled down:

[image]

Note: pixel measurements done with [Rooler](http://blois.us/Rooler/)